# Value pass to multiple include files

Tags: php, parameters, include

my index.php has 3 include files:

1 - checkpage.inc.php

```
if (!ISSET($_REQUEST['p'])){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page ORDER BY `porder` LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$pid = $row['pid'];
}
else {
$pid = $_REQUEST['p'];
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['lang'])) {
$lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];
} else {
$lang = 'en';
}
```

2 - header.inc.php (to call related page title, meta tags)
3 - nav.inc.php (to build related navigation links)

But it doesn't work. I have to put these code inside each inc.php can anyone tell me why the values doesn't pass to the include files? Or am I missing something else?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What values are you passing?

Comment: Are you using functions to include these files? Are the variables in the right scope?

Comment: Thanks Dale, you are right. Wrong scope....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass values when you include, the included file maintains the same scope of where it was included:

**index.php**

```
$foo = 'bar';
include 'header.inc.php';
```

**header.inc.php**

```
echo $foo;
// Outputs: bar
```